# How to create Custom map using AmCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

There are many beautiful charts on Geographical Maps that can be drawn with AmCharts JS library as in https://www.amcharts.com/demos/#javascript-maps

However, I was wondering if it is possible to **create a Custom Map**. For example, I want to create a Global map with all Color-coded countries, but want to **show US and Canada as one individual Country** without any intermediate boundary between them. All other Countries should remain same.

Really appreciate for any pointer on above direction.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you looked at [this tutorial](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/creating-custom-maps-for-javascript-ammap/)? It tells you how to create your own map.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also [group countries together](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/grouped-countries-map/) to make US and Canada behave as a single entity if you don't want to dive into the SVG and make your own changes.

Comment: Thanks xorspark. However, the problem with this approach is still the internal boundary between 2 underlying countries is visible as white line. Any idea how to erase internal boundary line?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `outlineAlpha` in `areasSettings`? It will get rid of most of the white line but there will still be a faint line due to how the map SVG/js files are made. It's the closest you'll get to removing the boundaries without modifying the map SVG/js files directly.

Answer (score 4):

With amCharts v4, we have switched to [using GeoJSON for our maps](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/map/).

While I'm sure there's some kind of [way to merge geographical polygons](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/issues/57) using [mapshaper](https://mapshaper.org/), I haven't tried it out myself yet and have been getting comfortable using the free software, [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/).

There's already [a tutorial out there on merging polygons](https://www.igismap.com/merge-two-polygons-points-polyline-shapefile/) if you're interested. I'll give a quick, specific rundown here anyway.

Download & install QGIS, then go ahead and grab the latest version of amCharts v4 `worldLow.json` (or `worldHigh.json` if you want more detail), in this case I've used `worldLow.json`:

https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4-geodata/blob/master/dist/script/json/worldLow.json

Raw file:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amcharts/amcharts4-geodata/master/dist/script/json/worldLow.json

- Make a copy of the .json file or otherwise rename it, it will be overwritten in the steps below.
- Open QGIS and start a new project
- Menu: Layer -> Add Vector Layer -> Source(s) -> Vector Dataset(s): Choose above file -> Add
- Enable editing on the layer by either: Clicking pencil icon, Menu: Layer -> Toggle Editing,  or in the bottom left Layers panel right click the layer and select Toggle Editing in the context menu
- Menu: Edit -> Select -> Select feature(s)
- Select the US and Canada polygons.
- Menu: Edit -> Merge selected features (near the bottom)

Save your project, save layer edits, now your json file will be updated.

It should look something like this:

https://gist.github.com/notacouch/485b8525a360c15690f1ab23cbf04940

Now to refer to this in your map, you can do so via:

```js
// Create map polygon series
var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
polygonSeries.geodataSource.url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/notacouch/485b8525a360c15690f1ab23cbf04940/raw/e6742c279571ae02166027817351a4250b1bea69/worldLow--canadia.json";
```

In addition, you can generate a new color per country by using the default `ColorSet`, e.g.

```js
// Have amCharts generate a new color for each mapPolygon once they're available
//
// Learn more about Event Listeners:
// {@link https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/event-listeners/}
polygonSeries.events.on("datavalidated", function() {
  polygonSeries.mapPolygons.each(function(polygon, index) {
    // Learn more about ColorSets:
    // {@link https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/colors/#Color_sets}
    polygon.fill = chart.colors.getIndex(index);
  });
});

// Create hover state and set alternative fill color
//
// Learn more about States:
// {@link https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/states/}
var hs = polygonTemplate.states.create("hover");

// Darken the polygon's current color
//
// Learn more about Adapters:
// {@link https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/adapters/}
hs.adapter.add("fill", function(fill) {
  return fill.brighten(-0.2);
});
```

Here's a demo with all that thrown together:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/abd95bebcfb65a74d9472043d63351fc

That's probably undesirable, you can also color via [data binding](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/map/#Binding_properties_to_data), or via a [heat map](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/map/#Geographical_heat_maps).

For customizing maps in v4 in general, I recommend checking out our guide on [Creating custom maps](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/creating-custom-maps/). Between mapshaper, QGIS, and all the map-related files out there, there's bound to be a way to get the customization you want and possibly in short order, too.

Hope this helps.